# XSLT concat select fields

Tags: xslt, concatenation

Can anyone help to concat those three fields into one new field? Thank you

```
<talents>
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='tasks']"/>
</talents>
<expectations>
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='talents']"/>
</expectations>
<benefits>
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Benefits']"/>
</benefits>
```

Comment: Please share a minimal source xml and the desired result xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put the text() values of the three source elements "tasks", "talents" and "Benefits"  into a single combined field "combined", then, to take this example input document:

```
<cv>
  <first-name>Al</first-name>
  <last-name>Truisme</last-name>
  <tasks>Make world safe for economy of expression</tasks>
  <talents>Total landscaping</talents>
  <Benefits>Dental</Benefits>
</cv>
```

You might be wanting this sort of output document:

```
<cv>
   <first-name>Al</first-name>
   <last-name>Truisme</last-name>
   <combined>Make world safe for economy of expression|Total landscaping|Dental</combined>
</cv>
```

and you can do it many ways, including with this XSLT3.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:variable name="targetElements" as="xs:string*" 
                select="( 'tasks', 'talents', 'Benefits' )" />
  
  <!-- assuming that "tasks", "talents" and "Benefits" have same parent -->
  <xsl:template match="*" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="nodesToExclude" as="node()*"
                    select="*[local-name() = $targetElements]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node() except $nodesToExclude" />
      <xsl:if test="count($nodesToExclude)" >
        <combined>{string-join($nodesToExclude, '|')}</combined>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*N.B. the capital 'B' in "Benefits" comes from your question but doesn't follow the pattern of the two other elements' names.*

Comment: There should never be a need to use a hack like `*[local-name() = XYZ]"`.

Comment: The OP used this to describe his elements.  I've re-used that here because I don't know what the OP's problem space is.  I would agree that it is not good usage, but I want to keep the solution space defined in terms of the problem space in order to have the solution make sense to the OP.

Comment: I don't think that's a good reason.